# Magento Enterprise upgrade from 1.9.0.0 to 1.14

Tags: magento, upgrade

Is there any best way to upgrade Magento Enterprise upgrade from 1.9.0.0 to 1.14 ?

I am trying to do same but getting error -

```
Error in file: "\xampp\htdocs\abc\app\code\core\Mage\Core\sql\core_setup\mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - Can't retrieve entity config: core/file_storage
```

how can I resolve this issue.

Please help!!

Comment: This sounds like it's more suitable in Magento's official support forums

Comment: For sure - not much point in paying $15K a year if you've got to come here asking for help.  You're paying for the support, you might as well use it.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot retrieve entity config: core/store_group error message means that default Magento configuration can not be initial on installation.

It can happen somebody accidentally moved/deleted files in app/code/core/Mage/Core directory, app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/etc for example.

My colleague move email queue from magento 1.9.1 to 1.9.0.1, we make some change on Core, then this error happened.

Check the .gitignore as well.